# Run chef cookook locally by keeping the cookbooks in remote server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

We can run the chef cookbook locally (chef-solo or chef-zero) as follows

```
chef-client -z --runlist 'recipe[cookbookname::recipename]'
```

Or

```
chef-client --local-mode C:\chefrepo\cookbooks\example\recipes\default.rb
```

However, how to run CHEF client in local mode by keeping the cookbooks in remote server? Something like this?

```
chef-client --local-mode \\10.10.1.1\cookbooks\example\recipe
```

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--config-option chef_repo_path=whatever` to control where the repo is located (by default it is `/var/chef` for `chef-solo` and `.` for local mode). That said, probably don't? Down the path of network filesystems for production file deployment lies much pain and suffering and unexplained outages. If you want a centralized storage system, that is literally what Chef Server is for.